# Running JAR from BAT file cannot find natives path

Tags: java, batch-file

I am running my JAR from a BAT file on Windows 7 x64 machine. Lately I added native .dll files to project, so now I need to add the path to the BAT. My project is exported to "C:/dist" and folder with native libs called "natives" placed alongside, that is "C:/dist/natives".

The problem is that for some reason the path is ignored, or cannot be found, or it seems something else is wrong in the BAT. This is my BAT code:

```
@ECHO OFF
java -XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx1G -server -Djava.library.path="C:/dist/natives" -jar data.jar
@if %errorlevel% neq 0 pause
```

When I run my project from the NetBeansIDE all works fine as expected. It is only when I try to run the compiled file from the BAT file it seems it cannot find the native libs when they are needed ending up with error.

I also tried add the path to the native libs [programaticaly](http://web.archive.org/web/20160214203937/http://blog.cedarsoft.com/2010/11/setting-java-library-path-programmatically/) like this:

```
//PROGRAMATICALLY SET THE PATH TO NATIVE LIBRARIES
System.setProperty("java.library.path", "natives");
Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
fieldSysPath.setAccessible(true);
fieldSysPath.set(null, null);
```

It works as it should in NetBeansIDE but not once the jar is compiled and run via BAT file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might have the same problem I mentioned at the beginning  of [this post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72148421/19018243), namely one of these:

- unnecessary jar files in your project (they might cause problems similar to yours)
- mixing different versions of LWJGL jar files (might cause problems similar to yours)
- mixing different versions of LWJGL native .dll files (might cause problems similar to yours)
- using unneeded native .dll files (sometime unnecessary ones may cause errors like yours)

Comment: yes, this was part of the problem of my other post - I mixed different versions of lwjgl jars (v2.9.3 and v3.3.0) in combination with native libs: once removed all is working as expected, thank you